# Llenar Inputs automaticamente dependienedo del valor ingresado en otro

Tags: html

[image]

Tegno este formulario y lo que quiero es cuando se ingrese un valor en cualquiera de los 3 campos de taza de interes, los otros dos se llenen automaticamente, sin la nesecidad de un boton o algo por el estilo

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Rellenar campo de formulario con el valor de otro campo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92029/rellenar-campo-de-formulario-con-el-valor-de-otro-campo)

Comment: tener en cuenta que en la respuesta enlazada "con el valor de otro campo" puede ser modificado por el cálculo que necesites